# How to share some source files along different PhoneGap projects?

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I have 3 different projects (developing on PhoneGap desktop for Windows). But they share some common functionalities. Currently I need to update the files on all www project folders when fixing/upgrade something of those shared functionalities. This is becoming a nightmare.

Example:

[image: projects structure]

Is there any way to link just one common folder to the projects using it?
Or any way to force PhoneGap desktop to copy into platform targets the files from just one source folder?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This site is supposed to ask what is not known. It is sad to see people putting -1 to the questions without an explanation. The one who did it here must be very bright!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hook to copy in the source files:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/

it looks like before_prepare should do this

Comment: MStoner, thanks for your answer. I'll check what are the hooks about!

Comment: It looks like PhoneGap desktop does not run hooks. Or at least I could not find any workable solution. I've tried all I found without success.